# Wordpress Breadcrumb switch without plugin (hide show breadcrumb)

Tags: php, wordpress, breadcrumbs

I'm looking for a button solution for breadcrumb.

I have a breadcrumb on the page that is under the header.

I would like to be able to turn it off / on on a given page / post.

I don't want to use an extra plugin.

Page settings = show or hide breadcrumb. I saw this option somewhere but I can't find the code.

Regards and thanks for help.

Comment: You should be able to do this by (1) Editing the theme file and removing the breadcrumb-related code. (2) Use CSS {display: none} on the html element that contains the breadcrumb.

Comment: I want to be able to turn on / off. Do not stick on rigidly display: none.

Comment: Some pages are supposed to have breadcrumb. Some are not. I need a switch :)

Comment: Then you will have to code it in a plugin or edit the theme. I don't see any other way.

Comment: It is true. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Paste this code into your functions.php (hopefully, in your child theme):

```
/* Adds page name to classes for page */
/* Modified is_single to is_singular, which targets both single archive and pages 
*/
/* Commented out echo statement, as it was showing up on the page output */
add_filter('body_class','page_class');
function page_class($classes) {
   global $wp_query;
   $page = '';
   $page = $wp_query->query_vars['pagename'];
   // add 'pagename' to the $classes array
   $classes[] = $page;
   // return the $classes array
   return $classes;
}
```

The slug of the page will now be pasted into the body html of the page. So, a page with slug this-is-me, will now have an html class of this-is-me. Target the breadcrumb html with that class in your css, to display: none;

That will affect only the page with that slug. So, do it for each page where you want to eliminate breadcrumbs.

Comment: Thank you! I needed something like this.